# Error: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, keyword

While connecting to my sql server  2010 with entity framework MVC4 this is my connection string

```
<add name="EmployeeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SqlExpress;initial catalog=Employee;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have tried the corrections like removing the metadata element of connection string and changing the connection string format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014 - so which one is it?